# Сильно различающиеся быстродействие цикла, с отладкой и без

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, .net-7

Минимальный код для воспроизведения проблемы.

```cs
  internal partial class Win32WPFWindowPositionUpdater
    {
        private readonly Window _window;
        private readonly Dispatcher _dispatcher;
        private const int IGNORE_SIZE_WINDOW = -1;
        private const int HWND_TOP = 0;
        private const int NOT_MESSAGE_WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING = 0x0400;
        private const int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
        private const int OFFSET_CURSOR = 30;
        public Win32WPFWindowPositionUpdater(Window window)
        {
            _window = window;
            _dispatcher = _window.Dispatcher;
        }
        public Task UpdateWindowPos(CancellationToken token) => UpdateWindowPositionRelativeToCursor(token);
        [LibraryImport("user32")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        internal static partial bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr handle, int handle2, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, int flag);
        private async Task UpdateWindowPositionRelativeToCursor(CancellationToken token)
        {
            WindowInteropHelper helper = new WindowInteropHelper(_window);
            while (token.IsCancellationRequested is not true)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1, token);

                if (token.IsCancellationRequested is true) return;
                Point point = GetCursorPosition();
                await _window.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
                {
                    SetWindowPos(helper.Handle, HWND_TOP, Convert.ToInt32(point.X - OFFSET_CURSOR), Convert.ToInt32(point.Y - OFFSET_CURSOR),
                        IGNORE_SIZE_WINDOW, IGNORE_SIZE_WINDOW, NOT_MESSAGE_WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING | SWP_NOSIZE);
                }, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render, token);
            }
        }
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct POINT
        {
            public int X;
            public int Y;

            public static implicit operator Point(POINT point)
            {
                return new Point(point.X, point.Y);
            }
        }
        [LibraryImport("user32")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static partial bool GetCursorPos(out POINT lpPoint);
        internal static Point GetCursorPosition()
        {
            GetCursorPos(out POINT lpPoint);
            return lpPoint;
        }
    }
}
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private readonly Win32WPFWindowPositionUpdater  _positionUpdater;
        private readonly CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _positionUpdater = new Win32WPFWindowPositionUpdater(this);

            _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

            _ = new Timer(new TimerCallback((_) =>
            {
                _positionUpdater.UpdateWindowPos(_tokenSource.Token);
            }), null, 1500, 0);

            _ = new Timer(new TimerCallback((_) =>
            {
                _tokenSource.Cancel();
            }), null, 7000, 0);
        }
    }
```

Визуально видно, что окно без отладки обновляет позицию окна медленнее. Если точнее, то вычисленная мною задержка между итерациями цикла обновления окна падает до 29% от изначальной. Причем на это влияет опция "горячая перезагрузка XAML", при её отключении в настройках Visual Studio. Скорость выполнения также падает.

Ожидаемое поведение - незначительные отклонения скорости выполнения цикла между режимами, с отладкой и без.

Это воспроизводимое поведение, или это проблемы на моём локальном компьютере? Если воспроизводимое, то по возможности разобраться в причинах, и устранить разницу.

UPDATE:

Будет выполнятся около 15 секунд.

```cs
 internal class Program
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();
            await MyTask();
            stopwatch.Stop();
            await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"{stopwatch.Elapsed}");
        }

        private static async Task<int> MyTask()
        {
          
            int count = 0;
            while (count < 1000)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1);
                count++;
                await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"{count}");
            }
            return count;
        }
    }
```

Это около 2-3 секунд.

```cs
 internal class Program
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();
            await MyTask();
            stopwatch.Stop();
            await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"{stopwatch.Elapsed}");
        }

        private static async Task<int> MyTask()
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                System.Windows.Window window = new System.Windows.Window();
         
                System.Windows.Application application = new System.Windows.Application();
                application.Run(window);
            });
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();

            int count = 0;
            while (count < 1000)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1);
                count++;
                await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"{count}");
            }
            return count;
        }
    }
```

Когда NET 7 и "горячая перезагрузка" включены.
Потому что приложение запросило таймер при `await Task.Delay(1)` в этом случаи, в отличии от первого. Убедится в этом можно прописав `powercfg -energy duration 1` в консоль, прочить файл отчёта.
[image: Отчёт]

UPDATE:
Оказывается недостаточно просто указать `await Task.Delay(1)`, на самом деле в большинстве случаев будет просто использоваться значение в  "15.625 ms".
[image: интервал]

Чтобы использовать меньшие величины нужен явный [вызов](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15071359/how-to-set-timer-resolution-from-c-sharp-to-1-ms) [timeBeginPeriod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timeapi/nf-timeapi-timebeginperiod)

P.S. В принце об этой задержки невнятно в документации по [Task.Dalay()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=net-7.0#system-threading-tasks-task-delay(system-int32)) написано.

Comment: А зачем это вообще? `Window.Left`, `Window.Top` чем не угодили? Если перетаскивать надо, то `Window.DragMove()` метод есть. А вообще это ожидаемое поведение, WPF UI в режиме отладки работает значительно медленнее.

Comment: `Task.Delay(1` - реальная задержка зависит от частоты таймера. Возможно, Студия меняет частоту таймера в зависимости от дебага/релиза. [Почему не стоит разгонять таймер Windows или мегаватты, потраченные впустую](https://habr.com/ru/companies/intel/articles/186998/) - рекомендую ознакомиться. Проверьте у себя частоту таймера, когда запускаете программу в разных режимах.

Comment: Объясняю.  `Window.DragMove()` вызывает исключение без зажатой клавиши мыши, я специально заглянул в реализацию - это ограничение самой функции WinApi. `Window.Left`, `Window.Top` там своя проблема, если реализовать такой цикл при минимальной задержки, получишь системный Exception о переполнении квоты. Лечится это передачей в метод `SetWindowPos` - `SWP_NOSENDCHANGING`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov . Я ознакомился со статьёй. Ситуация такая - при "powercfg -energy duration 5" и отладке, я наблюдаю в отчёте energy-report.html, что это приложение запросило таймер, так же как и ещё 4 других приложения. А вот без отладки в этот список оно не попадает. Что это значит? ". Я не понял, что именно под этим подразумевается. - "Проверьте у себя частоту таймера, когда запускаете программу в разных режимах"

Comment: Утилита clockres покажет частоту.

Comment: Так она показывает то же, что и в статье у автора. Не пойму чем мне эта информация полезна.

Comment: Current timer interval и в дебаге, и в релизе одинаковый?

Comment: "Current timer interval" относится к программе "Clockres". Он и будет одинаковый, так как таймер 1ms запрашивает 4 программы на компьютере. Хотя можно предположить, что если нет, то значение вероятно было бы другое. В зависимости от того в каком режиме запущено приложение. Как я говорил ранее, что в отладке есть запрос таймера, а без - нет.

Comment: Это значение относится не к программе Clockres, а является значением частоты системного таймера. Эту частоту некоторые приложения меняют. Исходя из поведения вашей программы, я предположил, что Visual Studio повышает частоту при отладке и уменьшает без неё - только так я могу объяснить такое поведение. / Но, конечно, другие приложения тоже могут это делать.

Comment: Это у меня походу на компе проблемы. У меня цикл обычный while (count < 1000) c await Task.Delay(1); Занимает 15 секунд, но если запустить еще один поток который вызовет просто создание окна приложение "просирается" запрашивая доступ к таймеру -1 мл. (и время становится нормальным). Что то с этим таймером сломалось.

Comment: Не у одного меня проблема.

Comment: @aepot есть идеи?

Comment: Идей больше нет, но какой смысл во всём этом? Борьба с системой? Ради чего?

Comment: Суть в том что у тебя 144hz монитор, и ты смотришь, а у тебя плавность изображения потерялось, так как 1/ 144 = 0.007 (7мс), что как оказалось меньше искусственной задержки.  Неприятно такое наблюдать.

Comment: Ну да, всё верно. Частота системного таймера Windows 15,625 (64 раза в секунду). Поэтому задавать в `Task.Delay` значение меньше 15 нет смысла - задержка всё равно будет 15,625 минимум. Но это если таймер работает на штатной частоте! А многие приложения её меняют, как описано в той статье по ссылке.

Comment: Это уже не актуально, если открыть документации по `timeBeginPeriod`. Я о том, что с определённой версии windows 10 это более не глобальный параметр, приложение само запрашивает этот диапазон и получает. А windows 11 вообще не гарантирует что ты его получишь.

Comment: А зачем в таком случае вообще системный вызов на задержку делать? Вы можете сделать свой однопоточный спин, который будет дергать вам делегат хоть раз в 5мс, вот только все равно вызов придется переадресовывать в UI контекст. Другими словами здесь надо уже от мыши отталкиваться, а не задержки. Например мониторить любое движение мыши, хоть раз в 5 мс, и если мышь пошла, сразу вызов перерисовки. Если мышь стоит - ничего не делать. Какой смысл рисовать одно и то же по таймеру поверх себя? Если речь про движение мыши поверх окна, то есть вообще готовый обработчик события `MouseMove`.

Comment: Экспериментально установил, что при задержке меньше 1ms, не приходит событие клика, а он же  останавливает обновление окна. В моем случаи это сценарий основной, подразумевается что все доступные ресурсы должны быть направленны на него, в данный момент времени. Я проверил если ли разница по загрузке цп между сохранением последний координаторы мыши, и при отличных координатах  фильтрации вызова функции `SetWindowPos` , и постоянным вызовом функции  `SetWindowPos` что там в простое загрузки 0.3-1% ЦП, что при обновлении окна около 10% разницы не заметил.  Логически вернее лишней раз не вызывать.

Comment: Почитал описание timeBeginPeriod. Не знал, что поведение так изменилось в последних версиях Винды. Спасибо!

Comment: Теперь хотелось бы знать, для чего нужна быстрая отрисовка окна при перемещении? Если речь о создании игры или чего-то подобного, то не лучше ли взять Unity или другой игровой фреймворк? WPF для этого не предназначен.

Comment: Мне тоже интересно, что не так с перетаскиванием окна за заголовок или `DragMove()`.